# How do I parse an HTML document with JSoup to get a list of links?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites to build a set of text/links to load a program dynamically with this information. So far I have done this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites").get();
Elements elms = doc.select("div.colmask"); // gets 7 countries
```

Below this tag there are `doc.select("div.state_delimiter,ul")` tags I am trying to get. I setup my iterator and go into a while look and call `iterator.next().outerHtml();`. I see all the tags for each country.

How can I step through each `div.state_delimiter`, pull that text then go down until
there is a `</ul>` which defines the end of the states individual counties/cities links/text?

I was playing around with this and can do it by setting `outerHtml()` to a `String` and then parsing the string manually, but I am sure there is an easier way to do this. I have tried `text()` and also tried `attr("div.state_delimiter")`, but I think I am messing up the pattern/routine to do this properly. Was wondering if someone could help me out here and show me how to get the div.state_delimiter into a text field and then the `<ul><li></li></ul>` I want all the `<li></li>` under the `<ul></ul>` for each state. Looking to grab the http:// && html that goes along with it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<ul>` containing the cities is the next sibling of the `<div class="state_delimiter">`. You can use [`Element#nextElementSibling()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling%28%29) to grab it from that div on. Here's a kickoff example:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites").get();
Elements countries = document.select("div.colmask");

for (Element country : countries) {
    System.out.println("Country: " + country.select("h1.continent_header").text());
    Elements states = country.select("div.state_delimiter");

    for (Element state : states) {
        System.out.println("\tState: " + state.text());
        Elements cities = state.nextElementSibling().select("li");

        for (Element city : cities) {
            System.out.println("\t\tCity: " + city.text());
        }
    }
}
```

The `doc.select("div.state_delimiter,ul")` doesn't do what you want. It returns *all* `<div class="state_delimiter">` **and** `<ul>` elements of the document. Manually parsing it by string functions makes no sense if you've already a HTML parser at hands.

Comment: awesome response, Thank You, I see it now and am playing with your example to get what I need.

Comment: Ran into another issue, got the categories and sub categories taken care of, but now I am stuck with the actual ad. url=http://mobile.craigslist.org/ctd/2555119167.html , I am selecting the body.posting and from there I am trying to get div.userbody but can not get this for some reason.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "I am stuck with the actual ad". I ran the above code locally and it printed all countries/states/cities nicely.

Comment: I hit return and the comment was posted before I actually wanted to complete the post... Your code above was awesome, helped me get the countries,states,cities, that example led me to get the categories and sub categories of each city.. but I am having trouble getting the actual ad.. I have identified the tags I need to be getting, but can not get past the body.posting tag @BalusC

Comment: There's no `<div class="userbody">`. There's only a `<div id="userbody">`. Fix your CSS selector. With an ID selector you don't need to preselect the body by the way. There shall always be only one element of it in the entire document. `Element userbody = document.select("#userbody").first();`.

Comment: You're welcome. For future unrelated questions please press `Ask Question` button :)

Comment: This was a great response. I had a similar problem that needed to be solved and this post put me on the right track. Thanks