# How to parse javascript from web page

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, jsoup

I need to get links from the javascript. I using jsoup, but it didn't work.

[screen](http://i62.tinypic.com/kd04jr.png)
 I need to get this link from the source of page. Can anyone help me how to do it?

```
    String url = "http://www.cda.pl/video/149016ec/Rybki-z-ferajny-2004-1080p-Dubbing-pl";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();


    Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");

    for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
           for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
               System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
           }
           System.out.println("-------------------");            
     }
```

I marked on screen what urls i want to get.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: Post your code - tell us what you've tried, tell us what you expect, tell us what you're experiencing.

Comment: Please don't confuse Java with JavaScript, they're fundamentally different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse an HTML document with JSoup to get a list of links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122415/how-do-i-parse-an-html-document-with-jsoup-to-get-a-list-of-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
    String url = "http://www.cda.pl/video/149016ec/Rybki-z-ferajny-2004-1080p-Dubbing-pl";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    //we pick the script node 
    Element script = doc.select("#player > script").get(0);
    String text = script.html();

    //then we parse the script for the desired uri
    final String prefix = "l='";
    int p1 = text.indexOf(prefix) + prefix.length();
    int p2 = text.indexOf("'", p1);
    String uri = text.substring(p1,  p2);

    System.out.println(uri);
```

It will give the desired output:

```
http://vgra001.cda.pl/lqcc6f8b3c8f76d1b58c1234813fcf67c7.mp4?st=SjoQ8DDcnH7pW8_XNNkA3w&e=1416438406
```

Please note that this is only a example, you will need to do error checking.

Now the explanation:

You almost had it done, you had the location of the code with the uri, then it was easy to find the important script node: You can see a `<div class="wrapqualitybtn">` near the `script` tag, then you can find the `div` that contains both your `script` tag and that `div` tag (the `<div id="player" ... >`, the script's tag parent node)

Once you have the script node you only need to do String parsing. Parsing javascript code could be risky because a little change in the code can break your parser, but I think in this case looking for `l='` is a solid bet.

A couple of advices:

- When a page uses jQuery you can use jQuery in browser console too! If you put `$('#player > script')[0]` In the browser you will see your script tag.
- You can search through the DOM of a page in Developer tools of your browser (F12) and then right click a node and click in `Copy CSS Path` (in chrome, something similar in firefox) And you will obtain a selector useable in JSoup.
- For a more resiliant script parsing you could use regular expressions instead of plain `indexOf` search.

I hope it will help, excuse me for the verbosity.